# Porting a project that is written for STM32 (ARM-Cortex M7 to NXP (ARM-Cortex M7)

Tags: stm32, nxp-microcontroller, arm7

The STM32 supply is very bad at the moment hence I am considering moving away from the STM32 and going for NXP since the supply is much better.

I would like to ask for advice regarding migrating from STM32 to NXP:

Have anyone tried to migrate their project from STM32 to NXP? Can this be done easily if the Core is the same?

What are the major difficulties that I may encounter?

Can I easily just remap pins, copy paste SPI/I2C and other drivers and they will just simply "work"

Comment: **Can I easily just remap pins, copy paste SPI/I2C and other drivers and they will just simply "work"** - no you can't.  You will need to rewrite peripheral drives.

Answer (score 1):

I have not gone through the migration, but consider that every single peripheral device (timers, Flash, SPI, I2C, etc) between two different micro manufacturers has a completely different register interface. This means that not a single thing works until you've implemented the new register interface. Usually this is handled by the manufacturers HAL, but those also have completely different C interfaces - so you're going to have to implement that, at the very least. So it's going to be a massive change no matter what. People who predict moving their code from one manufacturer to another usually build a porting layer in advance that hides the HAL, and swap out the HALs behind this layer. It mostly moves the development effort to another place (upfront) and starts reducing the work if there are more than 2 ports to maintain.

To get started it's best to have a quick look at the NXP HAL documentation on the peripherals you're using.